# How do use First Responder to call another UIViewController's method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, first-responder

I have been trying to follow along this article on how to use the First Responder.

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/09/the-amazing-responder-chain/

And it seems like if A view controller exists in side a container such as a navigation controller, I should be able to call a first responder method that is implemented in another view controller

Here is the layout in Storyboard:

UINavigationController -(relationship)-> UITableViewController1 -(push)-> UITableViewController2

I would like to implement a method in UITableViewController1

ie

```
- (void)coolMethod:(id) { ... }
```

But call the method in UITableViewController2

ie

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(coolMethod:) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

What I want is for the sendAction:to:from:forEvent: to send the action up to the UINavigationController and then and then send it down UITableViewController2

Is What I am trying to achieve a possibility?  What am I doing wrong?

(Also, I tried linking it up in storyboard, but it will not connect.  Clearly something is wrong but I do not know what I am missing)

Any help or advice you could give me would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't what the responder chain is for, and your VC1 is not in the responder chain for VC2. I guess you could implement your own navigation controller subclass to do this, but it wouldn't be good code.

What you're describing is better handled by giving VC2 a delegate property and making VC1 implement the dal agate protocol and set itself as the delegate when VC2 is pushed.

Comment: How would I put VC1 in the responder chain for VC2

Comment: You wouldn't. If you were going to do something you would pop out of the responder chain at the nav controller and then have your own code to redirect (presumably with some search logic for the correct controller).

Comment: Interesting.  I had assumed that when you push UIviewControllers into the navigation controller it would add them to a stack and essentially travel through the stack until you find someone that implements it.

Comment: @Calimari328 as Wain  is describing, you're going to want to use a delegate design pattern for what you are describing. Alternatively, you could also use notifications. The target for the article seems to be iOS 5/6 (it's around the time Devs had access to 6, but 5 was the most recent I think), so I imagine the design pattern presented has been updated since then

Comment: The responder chain is really the view hierarchy, but then it extends into the controller hierarchy if a view responder isn't found. But, it's a direct parent hierarchy, not a 'push' hierarchy or anything like that.